# CLLocation manager throws after ~30seconds

Tags: xamarin.ios, core-location

@ first I thought it wasn't firing, but saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058927/why-the-cllocationmanager-delegate-is-not-getting-called-in-iphone-sdk-4-0)

So I waited and now I get Unhandled Exception: MonoTouch.Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method: Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method' was thrown. in the failed handler.

I have defined a CLLocationManager, here is FinishedLaunching & CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
            {
                // If you have defined a view, add it here:
                // window.AddSubview (navigationController.View);

                _locationManager = new CLLocationManager();
                _locationManager.Delegate = new LocationManagerDelegate(this);
                _locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation();

                window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();


                return true;
            }




private class LocationManagerDelegate : CLLocationManagerDelegate
        {
            private AppDelegate _appd;
            public LocationManagerDelegate(AppDelegate appd)
            {
               _appd = appd;
                 Console.WriteLine("Delegate created");
            }
            public override void UpdatedLocation(CLLocationManager manager
                                                    , CLLocation newLocation, CLLocation oldLocation)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Lat: " + newLocation.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString());


            }
              public override void Failed (CLLocationManager manager, NSError error)
            {
                //_appd.labelInfo.Text = "Failed to find location";
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to find location");
                base.Failed (manager, error);
            }
        }
```

I am using the latest monodevelop, monotouch, xcode and iphone SDK, just installed a coupla days ago. Any suggestions?

Regards

_Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is saying you should not call base.Failed in the overridden "Failed" method.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  I'm still using 4.0.1

Comment: Just to add, it was still failing, I needed to turn airport on, even though I had a hardline