# CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation not calling locationManager:didUpdateLocations: or locationManager:didFailWithError:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to use the `CLLocationManager` framework in my iOS project to access the user's location but when I call

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]
```

neither `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` or `locationManager:didFailWithError:` are getting called.

```
//myViewController.h
@interface myViewController : UITableViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@end

//myViewController.m
@implementation myViewController{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

//edit
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}
//finish edit

-(void)getLocation
{
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                 message:@"Failed to Get Your Location"              
                                delegate:nil 
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = locations[[locations count] -1];
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

if (currentLocation != nil) {
   NSLog(@"latitude: %@", latitude);
   NSLog(@"longitude: @"%@", longitude);
}else {
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" 
                                                     delegate:nil 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

}
@end
```

Neither delegate method is being called despite what it says in the documentation:

"This method returns immediately. Calling this method causes the location manager to obtain an initial location fix (which may take several seconds) and notify your delegate by calling its `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method [...] In addition to your delegate object implementing the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method, it should also implement the `locationManager:didFailWithError:` method to respond to potential errors."

Don't know how to debug the issue.

Thanks,

JA

Comment: Is `getLocation` called? Did you looked for `locationServicesEnabled` returns or `authorizationStatus` returns?

Comment: yes, `get location` is called. Not totally sure what you mean by `locationServicesEnabled`. What should `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus` return?

Comment: did yo initialize location manager. [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]

Comment: Yea in `viewDidLoad` sorry I forgot to include that

Comment: Are you using simulator? If so, this has been asked way too many times on StackOverflow

Comment: No I'm running it on a device.

Comment: Were you ever prompted for location services? Did you select yes? Does it show up in Settings on the device?

Comment: I added the line `[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
` at the beginning of the `getLocation` method but it still doesn't prompt me...

Comment: if you are using ios 8, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working

Comment: Ah, @taylorcressy that is driving me crazy.  I am using the simulator, so a link to where it was already asked would be helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

[image]Just add this in info.plist

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription --- I need Location

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription --- I need Location

privacy - location usage description --- I need Location

Note that "I need Location" should be changed to describe your actual app's designed usage. It is communicated to the end user in the authorization message. (thanks @devios1)

```
  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  locationManager.delegate=self;
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
  locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
  [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Now it will call your didUpdateToLocation definitely.

for more details [click here](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/)

Comment: Note that "I need Location" should be changed to describe your actual app's designed usage. It is communicated to the end user in the authorization message.

Comment: Is it normal to start significant monitoring with standard location updates? Or are you supposed to pick one of the two?

Comment: Was struggling with this until I saw your answer. This: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription --- I need Location saved me. Thanks man

Comment: @Mohit tomar, hello sir method is not called yet in my app, i already add the keys in my plist file

Comment: Check Location permission for your app in settings.

Comment: Hi,  **[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];** is very important Line.

Comment: How many apps *really* need 'always'? I tend to allow apps to know my location only 'when in use'.

Answer (score 21):

You strongly need to check that you initialize CLLocationManager on main thread.
In other case you will not get updateLocation event.

I can't find such info in Apple docs but it works for me anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was my issue!  Also beware that for me, I would receive updateLocation events using the simulator, but not on the device.. perhaps because of architecture differences.  Cheers!

Comment: location manager requires to have run loop. You can have in on background thread as long as that thread has run loop. So for background thread you need to create run loop yourself.

Comment: Unbelievable! Just spent some hours figuring out, why locationmanager is not firing events (on macOS), but I did everything right, I was just not on the ui-thread. Thanks for this info.

Comment: You've just saved me from mental breakdown, after several hours of senseless debugging. I owe you a gift at Christmas.

Answer (score 13):

Location Services work a bit differently starting in iOS 8.

Mainly, you need to add a key `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to your **Info.plist** file, and add a description why your app need Location, such as "Location needed to ...".

Note that you might also have to check for iOS version. Only iOS 8 and up have the Location Manager listen to the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` call.

The link below shows more details:
http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Good luck!

Comment: great!.. the link that you describe above "http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/" was really helpful

Comment: Link is very helpful.

Comment: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription was the key, i wasted 2 hours finding this little knob, the String you put in there is presented to the end user as a reason why you need access to the current location.

Answer (score 5):

With iOS 8.0 you need to call `-[CLLocationManager  requestWhenInUseAuthorization
]` or `-[CLLocationManager  requestAlwaysAuthorization]` first so the user gets asked to give your app permission to use the location.

Comment: I added the line [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];  at the beginning of the getLocation method but it still doesn't prompt me...

Comment: go to your phone's settings->privacy->location services and make sure it's On, then see what options you have for your app. if it's been denied at some point, the app will never prompt again.

Comment: Try this one [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]

Answer (score 4):

You need to add below things to your project,

1. In plist of your project add these things:

   1. `Key: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription Type:String`
   2. `Key: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription Type:String`
2. In the .m file with `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` add this condition :

   ```
   if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];`
   ```

Then only your `CLLocationManager` delegate methods will get called.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check this link.You are not retaining the location manager object when declaring.

please give property to you object
@property(nonatomic, strong)

[Why the CLLocationManager delegate is not getting called in iPhone SDK 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058927/why-the-cllocationmanager-delegate-is-not-getting-called-in-iphone-sdk-4-0)

Answer (score 1):

So if you are running in simulator don't forget to set location in simulator menu. It looks like if it is set to none nothing is called in delegate... I am not sure than if this can happen on real device too but probably it's simulator specific.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following in my code base:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if( status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ) {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        _locationManager.distanceFilter = 200;
    }
}
```

Turns out that this was getting called in an infinite loop, because initializing a locationManager triggers this method for some reason? I had not realized that. I had put it there to catch when permissions were granted. Instead, I set up a location manager and started updating the location, but then this fired and replaced it with one that wasn't updating the location, and kept looping over and over.

Solution for me was just to add `&& !_locationManager` to the if condition.